# Function undefined inside Underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have some Underscore.js template that renders completely fine, except, the function called inside that template is undefined. For example:

```
<span class='<% checkClass(oldValue, newValue) %>'>
```

The function itself works completely fine outside the template and returns the class name as expected. Does Underscore templates have their our scope?

**UPD:** That's how template is defined and called:

```
function checkClass() {... return 'Something' ...}

pData = [Object]; //Just for reference

var rowsTpl = _.template("<span class='<% checkClass(oldValue, newValue) %>'>");

_.each(pData, function (vals, name) {

    prOutput = rowsTpl(vals);

    $(this.elem).html(prOutput);

});
```

Comment: Can you please add how you render/call this template? Note: you've to explicitly pass data and functions as object to the template (including any function you may use).

Comment: Sure, updated in original post. 
Documentation is, probably, not much clear about it? Can you tell a bit more about it? Is there a way to pass multiple objects?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out (as I think) the right way. In my case, I have to pass my own object to template, including the needed functions or data:

```
var rowsTpl = _.template("<span class='<% func.checkClass(val.oldValue, val.newValue) %>'>");
```

Notice, that I am accessing *checkClass* function from **func** object and *oldValue* and *newValue* from **val** object. Here is the declaration:

```
_.each(pData, function (vals, name) {

    outPut += rowsTpl({
        name: name,
        val: vals,
        func: {
            checkClass: checkClass,
            anyOtherThing: thing
        }
    });

});
```